# Windows 10 Defender detects everything

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am creating a file with Python script. only this:

```
def Start():
   print('Hi')
   f=open("file1.txt", "a+")
Start()
```

But Windows Defender detects the output of the executable file as a trojan.

The 'autopytoexe' tool is used to create the executable file.

Comment: That sounds like a Windows Defender problem regarding AutoPyToExe (PyInstaller) executables. I'm not quite sure what you might be able to do here.

Comment: Maybe give a try to [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) to compile the executable and see if this keeps happening

Answer (score 0):

I tackled it by disabling the Windows Defender.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea for a bunch of other reasons